# How to do query with join on the same table and then group results by first column and count results in each group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a query on some geographic points like this it will give all points with distance between them lower then some threshold.

What I want to do is get all points that doesn't have another points near them.

One way to do that is somehow group results by a.id and them count results in each group. For points with no neighbours the count would be equal to one.

```
    select a.id, b.id
    from channel a, channel b
    where ST_Distance_Spheroid(
        a.coordinates,
        b.coordinates,
        'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'
    ) <= 1000.0
group by
a.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

But this actually doesn't work. postgres tells me that I need b.id somehow in groupby for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove `b.id` from your `select`:

```
select a.id
from channel a join
     channel b
     on ST_Distance_Spheroid(a.coordinates,
                             b.coordinates,
                             'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'
                             ) <= 1000.0
group by a.id
having count(*) = 1;
```

Personally, I think `not exists` is easier to understand and probably faster:

```
select a.id
from channel a 
where not exists (select 1
                  from channel b
                  where a.id <> b.id and
                        ST_Distance_Spheroid(a.coordinates,
                                             b.coordinates,
                                             'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'
                                            ) <= 1000.0;
```

Comment: Can you explain what select 1 and a.id <> b.id mean?

Comment: `Select 1` just mean you find something so `not exist` will be false. `a.id <> b.id` mean the distance between two different objects. no with itself.

Comment: btw not sure if `ST_Distance_Spheroid` can use the Spatial Indexm, you should check the explain plain. You should try `ST_DWithin`  http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_DWithin.html

Answer (score 0):

I rather use `ST_DWithin` because I'm sure use spatial index.

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html

```
SELECT 
      a.id,
      ST_Distance_Spheroid(a.coordinates,
                           b.coordinates,
                           'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'
                          ) as distance -- just to validate distance value
FROM       channel a
LEFT JOIN  channel b
  ON a.id <> b.id
 AND ST_DWithin(a.coordinates,
                b.coordinates,        
                1000)   -- You have to check the numeric distance match your projection

WHERE b.id is null
```